# How to configure two machines to communicate over spread

Tags: integration, multicast, spread-toolkit

I have to machines in the same network that should communicate over the [Spread Toolkit](http://www.spread.org/)
Both machines have the same config file

```
Spread_Segment  129.70.129.255:4803 {
 cadmium 129.70.129.13
 palladium 129.70.129.12
}
```

Spread starts correctly on both machines but doesn't show the other machine.
Actually sending messages doesn't work either.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

129.70.129.255 is intended to be a broadcast address. If this isn't a broadcast adress spread won't be able to send events. You can find the correct broadcast address with ifconfig on a linux command line.

If your network equipment (switches etc.) block broadcast packets for your network you may have luck with multicast. You can use 225.0.0.1 instead of 129.70.129.255 to use multicast.